# Finding numbers with a certain format

Tags: python, regex

I have to find all the numbers in a file that follow a specific format.  The format is as follows:

Each number is positive or negative (the sign might or might not be present, there are one or more digits before the decimal place, and one or more digits after the decimal place). There might not be a decimal place. There can be spaces before and after each number. Two numbers are separated by commas (,) or semicolons (;) or colons (:). For example
  (35.3 , 52.23; -623, 623.62 : -52,65)

So in the above example there are six numbers that I want listed.  The list of numbers to be searched is between parenthesis.  Until now my code looks like this:

```
def number_processing( file_location ):
    """"""

    import re

    file_variable = open( file_location )
    lines = file_variable.readlines()

    numbers = re.compile(r'[(] *[+]?[-]?[0-9][0-9]*[.]+[,]+[;]+[0-9][0-9]* *[)]')
    numbers_list = []

    for line in lines:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            match = numbers.match(word)
            if match:
                numbers_list.append(match.group())
      print numbers_list
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `str.split`, how about just using `re.findall`?

```
>>> s = '35.3 , 52.23; -623, 623.62 : -52,65'
>>> re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?', s)
['35.3', '52.23', '-623', '623.62', '-52', '65']
```

---

***edit:*** to only search inside parentheses pairs, you can write another regex to find those first, and then reuse the one above:

```
>>> s = '(23432.434 , 32423, -4343; 343) 5555 (3244, 45445; -4545 )'
>>> for s_ in re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', s):
...   re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?', s_)
... 
['23432.434', '32423', '-4343', '343']
['3244', '45445', '-4545']
```

To join all the above sub-lists in a list comprehension:

```
>>> s = '(23432.434 , 32423, -4343; 343) 5555 (3244, 45445; -4545 )'
>>> pat1 = re.compile(r'\(.*?\)')
>>> pat2 = re.compile(r'[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?')
>>> [x for s_ in re.findall(pat1, s) for x in re.findall(pat2, s_)]
['23432.434', '32423', '-4343', '343', '3244', '45445', '-4545']
```

Comment: Nifty answer. +1 for conciseness :D

Comment: Thank you for your response, the code works great.  However, I need help to tweak it a little, the set of numbers are closed in a pair of parentheses, there might be more than one set in the file.  For example:         (23432.434 , 32423, -4343; 343) 5555 (3244, 45445; -4545 ).  I don't want the 5555 to show up in my function output.      Thanks again!

Comment: OK, well can you guarantee well-formed parentheses?  And will there be any nested parentheses?

Comment: Yes, there will always be at least a pair of parentheses enclosing a group of numbers with the above format.  Also, no, there will not be any nested parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already splitting by space, a regex something like...

```
[(]?[+-]?\d+\.?\d+[,;:]?[)]?
```

(Not sure if you must escape the parentheses...just check ;D

AND

[+]?[-]? - What's with this? You are telling your regex that a + and - may occur both, though it is possible that one or both of them is absent.

And, the whole of your regex tries to recognize two separate numbers at once (if I get what you mean by commas, semicolons and colons right), the second one an integer at that. There are a lot of test cases where what you won't get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just consume these tokens with a regex, run the expression globally and eat numbers, dashes, and decimal points in a greedy, simple fashion:

```
/[\d.-]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find all the numbers, why not do something like:

```
re.findall(r'[+-\d.]', text)
```

And not worry about the extraneous formatting?

(Note: this will match e.g. `+2323.`, which is weird input, but Python can deal with it. If you do

```
map(float, re.findall(r'[+-\d.]', text))
```

you'll still get a nice pretty list of floats.)